# Update div after jquery ajax request only if content is new

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've recently started learning jQuery and I'm trying to make a little messaging system, I've gotten the messages to update every 2 seconds. However, I don't want the messages to update if there aren't any new messages. This is my current message updating code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("get_messages.php", function (result) {
        if ($('.messages').html() != result){
        $('.messages').html(result);
        }
    });
}, 2000);
```

});

The if statement doesn't seem to be working even though the div and result should be the same.

Comment: how about you try `!==`

Comment: @erkaner I've tried it. That doesn't work either

Comment: how many items do you have with `.messages` class? only one?

Comment: `var existing = if ($('.messages').html();` and `var new = result;` can you add these two lines and debug it, and check if their values are valid and see if they are equal really?

Comment: @erkaner I've added the following code var existing = $('.messages').html();
   if (existing != result){ $('.messages').html(result);
   }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74765/discussion-between-erkaner-and-user4559334).

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have timestamp or messageID on server that could tell your script if there are new messages after last check.

ex.

```
var lastMessageID = 0;
function checkMessages(){
$.ajax(url,{

    data:{
       last_message_id:lastMessageID
    },
    success:function(data){
    // Count new messages
    if (Object.keys(data).length > 0){  
        $.each(data,function(index, item){
            $('.messages').prepend("<span class='message'>"+item.message+"</span>");
    });
    // We suggest that this is our last message 
    lastMessageId = data[Object.keys(data).length-1].id;
    }
 }
});
}
var intervalM = setInterval(function(){
     checkMessages();
},2000);
```

And please save some trees by using gziped JSON data. :)

Comment: What's gzipped json data?

Comment: json is a lightweight data. It' s necessary to define headers at the top of your php script for that:
<?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); ?>

and to convert array to json data, you have to use: json_encode($array);

Please search stackoverflow for more informations on this, there are lot  of good examples. :)